# Is there any way we can detect more than 12 landmark points in google face detection ML Kit

Tags: java, android, face-detection, google-vision, facial-landmark-alignment

I am trying to detect upper lip coordinate from google ml kit api, but according to google vision api, i can only detect 12 landmark position on face ,, can someone help me out with this problem.

Comment: according to this: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/face-detection-concepts#contours. Upper lip is from point 106-116. Have you read carefully?

Comment: Thanks, i got the desired result.